# Combine variance from two linear models

Tags: variance, linear-model, analytical

I used here linear models for simplifying my final approach. Let's assume that a first linear model is estimated to obtain a response that will be then used as covariate in a successive linear model. How could one analytically find the uncertainty around the response of the second model, presuming that uncertainty in the first model should echo in the second one.

In equations, the first model is given by
$$x_{i} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 z_{i} + \epsilon_{i}\, .$$

Fitted values from the previous equation will be the covariate of the following linear model:
$$y_{i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat{x}_{i} + \nu_{i}\, .$$

Both $\epsilon_{i}$ and $\nu_{i}$ are common homoscedastic error terms.

Is there an analytic formulation for $Var(\mathbf{y})$ which accounts for $Var(\mathbf{x})$?

A workaround could be the computation of $Var(\mathbf{x})$ from the variance-covariance matrix of the first model and then a bootstrap procedure for the second model by simulating, for each bootstrapped instance, new values for $\mathbf{x}$ using estimated mean and variance.

Only for illustrative purposes you can find below this first "half-analytical" solution by means of simulated data. I wrote it in `R`, but I extensively commented and used basic routines to broaden the readership.

Any help will be obviously highly appreciated.

````
## number of data-points
n <- 100
## simulating x from model 1
alphasT <- c(1,2)
Z <- cbind(1,seq(0, 1, length=n))
sigma.x <- 0.8
x <- Z%*%alphasT + rnorm(n, 0, sigma.x)
## estimating model 1
tZZ <- t(Z)%*%Z
tZZ1 <- solve(tZZ)
tZx <- t(Z)%*%x
x.hat <- Z%*% tZZ1 %*% tZx
## Variance (and standard errors) of x.hat
res.x <- x-x.hat
RSSx <- sum(res.x^2)
sigma2.x.hat <- RSSx/(n-2)
V.alphas <- tZZ1*sigma2.x.hat
V.x.hat <- Z %*% V.alphas %*% t(Z)
se.x.hat <- sqrt(diag(V.x.hat)) 

## model for y (given the previously fitted x)
## simulating y assuming we know x.hat
betasT <- c(2,3)
X <- cbind(1,x.hat)
sigma.y <- 1.5
y <- X%*%betasT + rnorm(n, 0, sigma.y)
## estimating the model
tXX <- t(X)%*%X
tXX1 <- solve(tXX)
tXy <- t(X)%*%y
y.hat <- X%*% tXX1 %*% tXy
## standard errors assuming x.hat as given
res.y <- y-y.hat
RSSy <- sum(res.y^2)
sigma2.y.hat <- RSSy/(n-2)
V.betas <- tXX1*sigma2.y.hat
V.y.hat <- X %*% V.betas %*% t(X)
se.y.hat <- sqrt(diag(V.y.hat)) 
## analytic confidence intervals assuming x.hat as given
y.up <- y.hat + 1.96*se.y.hat
y.low <- y.hat - 1.96*se.y.hat

## uncertainty around y by bootstrap 
## with different x.hat at each instance
## simulated from estimated mean and variance

## number of bootstrapped instances
nb <- 1000
## where to save all nb fitted y
Ys.hat <- matrix(0, n, nb)
for(i in 1:nb){
  ## sample residuals
  res.y.s <- sample(res.y, replace=TRUE)
  ## bootstrapped y
  y.s <- y.hat + res.y.s
  ## simulating x.hat
  x.hat.s <- rnorm(n, mean=x.hat, sd=se.x.hat)
  ## estimating bootstrapped y for a given simulated x (here I use lm())
  fit.y.s <- lm(y.s ~ x.hat.s)
  ## save fitted bootstrapped y for a given simulated x
  Ys.hat[,i] <- fit.y.s$fitted
}
## extract 95% empirical confidence interval for y 
y.up.b <- apply(Ys.hat, 1, quantile, probs=0.975)
y.low.b <- apply(Ys.hat, 1, quantile, probs=0.025)

## plotting simulated and estimated y 
## and both 95% confidence intervals from both approaches
plot(x.hat, y)
lines(x.hat, y.hat, col=2)
lines(x.hat, y.up, col=3, lty=2, lwd=3)
lines(x.hat, y.low, col=3, lty=2, lwd=3)
lines(x.hat, y.up.b, col=4, lty=3, lwd=3)
lines(x.hat, y.low.b, col=4, lty=3, lwd=3)
```
````